# Using Subclipse with share drive specifically an office-like share drive

Tags: eclipse

Apologies for the simplicity for the quention but I'm new with using SVN tools and I've recently installed Subclipse and I want to share a project onto a locally specifically onto an office-like share drive

Is this possible? If not which subversioning tool can I use for commiting/sharing work locally specifically onto an office-like share drive

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Any SVN client, including Subclipse should let you work on any drive.

Comment: Hi Lee. Thanks for the reply. So essentially when sharing my project using subclipse when I'm required to enter teh URL I should enter my the URL target belonging to the share drive e.g. \\Sys-Storage\\AndroidDev\\? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to know what you are asking. Typically the URL you entered would be the URL of your SVN repository.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the SVN book, chapter 1:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html

You need a SVN server and repository.  That is what you will "share" with.  All users that want to collaborate on the versions of a file will need to use a SVN client so that they can checkout and edit files stored in your repository and commit their changes back.